# Making a perfect loop with stroke of a svg rectangle

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I hope you're doing well! ✨

I'm currently trying to reproduce this effect around the video: https://thinkmojo.com/

Here is what I did: I've my paths with the gradient and on top, the "mask" which is just a white rectangle.

SVG

```css
.mask {
  animation: mask 15s infinite linear;
  stroke-dasharray: 678;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes mask {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2700;
  }
}


/* data lengths
length top/bottom: 678px
length right/left: 417px
total length: 2190px
```

```html
<svg fill="none" height="423" viewBox="0 0 684 423" width="684" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="420" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f909f7" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="681.5" x2="681.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#11f70d" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="3" y2="3">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#11f70d" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="d" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.5" x2="3.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f909f7" />
 </linearGradient>
 <g stroke-width="4">
  <g stroke-linecap="square">
   <path d="m681 420h-678" stroke="url(#a)" />
   <path d="m681 3v417" stroke="url(#b)" />
   <path d="m681 3h-678" stroke="url(#c)" />
   <path d="m3 420v-417" stroke="url(#d)" />
  </g>
  <path class="mask" d="m3 3h678v417h-678z" stroke="white" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

I can't manage to make a perfect loop, I don't know, I'm missing something on the values and it drives me nuts...

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Add the snippet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, I recommend rearranging your four sides so that they start in the top right and proceed anti-clockwise around your rectangle in sequence, and are drawn in the correct directions.  This should make the animations a little easier to understand.

I chose to start in the top right because that is what the original thinkmojo one does.

Next we need to consider what the dash pattern needs to be.

If this was one complete rectangle, rather than four individual sides, it would be easy. The dash is the length of one of the long sides. And the gap needs to be the sum of the lengths of the other three sides (678 + 417 + 417 = 1512).

```
stroke-dasharray: 678 1512
```

And in fact, this is the same dash pattern we need to use in our case.  For the first side (the top), we just cycle this dash pattern continuously.  To do that we animate the `stroke-offset` by -2190 to make it appear to move in a forward (anti-clockwise) direction.  We can either animation from 0 to -2190, or alternatively from 2190 to 0.  The latter is the better choice because Safari has a bug where it doesn't handle negative dash offsets correctly.

For a first step, let's just create the animated dash patterns, as described above, and just have them all start at the same time.

```css
.square path {
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-dasharray: 678 1512;
  animation: mask 15s infinite linear;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2190;
}

@keyframes mask {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg fill="none" height="423" viewBox="0 0 684 423" width="684" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="green_yellow" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="3" y2="3">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
    <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#11f70d" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="yellow_magenta" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.5" x2="3.5" y1="3" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f909f7" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="magenta_blue" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="420" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f909f7" />
    <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#0704f4" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="blue_green" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="681.5" x2="681.5" y1="3" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#11f70d" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0704f4" />
   </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g class="square">
   <path d="m681 3h-678" stroke="url(#green_yellow)" class="top" />
  <path d="m3 3v417" stroke="url(#yellow_magenta)" class="left" />
  <path d="m3 420h678" stroke="url(#magenta_blue)" class="bot" />
  <path d="m681 420v-417" stroke="url(#blue_green)" class="right" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

To complete our animation, all we should need to do now is to adjust the animations of the left, bottom and right sides so that they start at precisely the correct time to make the loop appear continuous.

To work out the timings, we need to work out what the time to animate each side is.  Assuming an animation time of 15 seconds, and a circumference of 2190 units, the time to travel each of the sides will be:

- long sides: `15s * 678 / 2190 = 4643.8 mS`
- short sides: `15s * 417 / 2190 = 2856.2 mS`

Because our stroke array starts with the dash visible, we need to set our start time for the other three sides "back in time" effectively.  For example, for the left side, we want the dash to start just off the start of the line.  So one dash length before time=0. 
 Meaning effectively `-4643.8 mS`.  Luckily CSS provides a way to do that using a negative `animation-delay`. It's a little confusing, but to start the animation at time=-4643.8, we actually have to specify a time of `-animationDuration + startTime` or `(-15000 - 4643.8) = -10356.2 mS`.

If you do the same calculation for the bottom side, it works out as `animation-delay -7500ms`. And for the right side it will be `animation-delay: -2856.2ms`.

```css
.square path {
  stroke-width: 4;
  stroke-linecap: square;
  stroke-dasharray: 678 1512;
  animation: mask 15s infinite linear;
  stroke-dashoffset: 2190;
}

@keyframes mask {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

.square .left {
  animation-delay: -10356.2ms;
}

.square .bottom {
  animation-delay: -7500ms;
}

.square .right {
  animation-delay: -2856.2ms;
}
```

```html
<svg fill="none" height="423" viewBox="0 0 684 423" width="684" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
   <linearGradient id="green_yellow" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="3" y2="3">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
    <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#11f70d" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="yellow_magenta" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.5" x2="3.5" y1="3" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f909f7" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="magenta_blue" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="420" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f909f7" />
    <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#0704f4" />
   </linearGradient>
   <linearGradient id="blue_green" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="681.5" x2="681.5" y1="3" y2="420">
    <stop offset="0" stop-color="#11f70d" />
    <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0704f4" />
   </linearGradient>
  </defs>

  <g class="square">
   <path d="m681 3h-678" stroke="url(#green_yellow)" class="top" />
  <path d="m3 3v417" stroke="url(#yellow_magenta)" class="left" />
  <path d="m3 420h678" stroke="url(#magenta_blue)" class="bottom" />
  <path d="m681 420v-417" stroke="url(#blue_green)" class="right" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

We could have also adjusted the animation timings by setting individual starting and ending `stroke-dashoffset` values for each side.

Comment: Wow thanks Paul! Thank you for detailing the response!
I didn't know you could put 2 values in dasharray, but I understand it now, super cool, thanks again :D

Answer (score 2):

I've make the `stroke-dasharray: 678 417` meaning strokes of 417 and gaps of 678. Also I've animated the stroke-dashoffset `to {stroke-dashoffset: 2190;}`

```css
.mask {
  animation: mask 15s infinite linear;
  stroke-dasharray:417 678;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes mask {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2190;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg fill="none" viewBox="0 0 684 423" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="420" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f909f7" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="681.5" x2="681.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#11f70d" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="3" y2="3">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#11f70d" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="d" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.5" x2="3.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f909f7" />
 </linearGradient>
 <g stroke-width="4">
  <g stroke-linecap="square">
   <path d="m681 420h-678" stroke="url(#a)" />
   <path d="m681 3v417" stroke="url(#b)" />
   <path d="m681 3h-678" stroke="url(#c)" />
   <path d="m3 420v-417" stroke="url(#d)" />
  </g>
  <path class="mask" d="m3 3h678v417h-678v-417z" stroke="white"id="mask" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you Enxaneta for your answers, Paul's answer is more what I expected but thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for ?

```css
.mask {
  /*animation: mask 15s infinite linear;*/
  animation: mask 4s infinite linear;
  stroke-dasharray: 678;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;

}

@keyframes mask {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2700;
  }
}


/* data lengths
length top/bottom: 678px
length right/left: 417px
total length: 2190px
*/
```

```html
<svg fill="none" height="423" viewBox="0 0 684 423" width="684" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
 <linearGradient id="a" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="420" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f909f7" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="b" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="681.5" x2="681.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#11f70d" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#0704f4" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="c" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3" x2="687" y1="3" y2="3">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset=".989583" stop-color="#11f70d" />
 </linearGradient>
 <linearGradient id="d" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="3.5" x2="3.5" y1="3" y2="420">
  <stop offset="0" stop-color="#f9fb42" />
  <stop offset="1" stop-color="#f909f7" />
 </linearGradient>
 <g stroke-width="4">
  <g stroke-linecap="square">
   <path d="m681 420h-678" stroke="url(#a)" />
   <path d="m681 3v417" stroke="url(#b)" />
   <path d="m681 3h-678" stroke="url(#c)" />
   <path d="m3 420v-417" stroke="url(#d)" />
  </g>
  <path class="mask" d="m3 3h678v417h-678z" stroke="white" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

I have made changes(modified `store-dashoffset` value and added `animation-fill-mode`) to make your animation look continuous and it makes complete loops.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Hey thanks for helping,
Well it's not really like the example, there is 2 "path" instead of one and you can see in the top left corner that it doesn't loop perfectly, I hope it's clear :)